# How to compile all lists in a column into one unique list

Tags: python, list, pandas, merge, unique

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

[image]

How can I combine all the lists (in the 'val' column) into a unique list (set), e.g. `[val1, val2, val33, val9, val6, val7]`?

I can solve this with the following code. I wonder if there is an easier way to get all unique values from a column without iterating the dataframe rows?

```
def_contributors=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    contri = ast.literal_eval(row['val'])
    def_contributors.extend(contri)
def_contributors = list(set(def_contributors))
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another solution with exporting `Series` to nested `lists` and then apply `set` to flatten list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b', 'c'], 'val':[['val1','val2'],
                                               ['val33','val9','val6'],
                                               ['val2','val6','val7']]})

print (df)
  id                  val
0  a         [val1, val2]
1  b  [val33, val9, val6]
2  c   [val2, val6, val7]

print (type(df.val.ix[0]))
<class 'list'>

print (df.val.tolist())
[['val1', 'val2'], ['val33', 'val9', 'val6'], ['val2', 'val6', 'val7']]

print (list(set([a for b in df.val.tolist() for a in b])))
['val7', 'val1', 'val6', 'val33', 'val2', 'val9']
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [307]: %timeit (df['val'].apply(pd.Series).stack().unique()).tolist()
1 loop, best of 3: 410 ms per loop

In [355]: %timeit (pd.Series(sum(df.val.tolist(),[])).unique().tolist())
10 loops, best of 3: 31.9 ms per loop

In [308]: %timeit np.unique(np.hstack(df.val)).tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop

In [309]: %timeit (list(set([a for b in df.val.tolist() for a in b])))
1000 loops, best of 3: 558 µs per loop
```

---

If types is not `list` but `string` use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b', 'c'], 'val':["[val1,val2]",
                                               "[val33,val9,val6]",
                                               "[val2,val6,val7]"]})

print (df)
  id                val
0  a        [val1,val2]
1  b  [val33,val9,val6]
2  c   [val2,val6,val7]

print (type(df.val.ix[0]))
<class 'str'>

print (df.val.str.strip('[]').str.split(','))
0           [val1, val2]
1    [val33, val9, val6]
2     [val2, val6, val7]
Name: val, dtype: object

print (list(set([a for b in df.val.str.strip('[]').str.split(',') for a in b])))
['val7', 'val1', 'val6', 'val33', 'val2', 'val9']
```

Comment: i have added this when importing the csv file, so that the val column will be recognized as list object type : converters={"val": literal_eval}

Comment: What's the most concise way to get around the issue of one of the rows being NaN? Having at least one NaN row gets TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: `print (list(set([a for b in df.val.dropna().str.strip('[]').str.split(',') for a in b])))`
does the trick!

Answer (score 7):

Convert that column into a DataFrame with `.apply(pd.Series)`. If you stack the columns, you can call the `unique` method on the returned Series.

```
df
Out[123]: 
            val
0      [v1, v2]
1      [v3, v2]
2  [v4, v3, v2]
```

---

```
df['val'].apply(pd.Series).stack().unique()
Out[124]: array(['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to extract those elements into an array using `np.hstack` and then using `np.unique` to give us an array of such unique elements, like so -

```
np.unique(np.hstack(df.val))
```

If you want a list as output, append with `.tolist()` -

```
np.unique(np.hstack(df.val)).tolist()
```

Comment: Very interesting, I think your solution will be faster as list comprehension with `set`, but not.

Comment: @jezrael Yeah that `hstack` isn't helping much I guess. Ah nevermind I did at my end and is even slower!

Comment: It is more slowier `In [310]: %timeit np.unique(np.concatenate(df.val))
10 loops, best of 3: 39.6 ms per loop`

Comment: @jezrael Yeah, even slower with `np.concatenate`. Guess not much NumPy can do here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) followed by some `string` manipulations to obtain the desired `list`.

```
In [60]: import re
    ...: from collections import OrderedDict

In [62]: s = df['val'].str.cat()

In [63]: L = re.sub('[[]|[]]',' ', s).strip().replace("  ",',').split(',')

In [64]: list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(L))
Out[64]: ['val1', 'val2', 'val33', 'val9', 'val6', 'val7']
```