# Python Pandas : How to return grouped lists in a column as a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by

[Python Pandas : How to compile all lists in a column into one unique list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895856/python-pandas-how-to-compile-all-lists-in-a-column-into-one-unique-list/38896038#38896038)

Starting with data from previous question:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b', 'a'], 'val':[['val1','val2'],
                                               ['val33','val9','val6'],
                                               ['val2','val6','val7']]})

print (df)
  id                  val
0  a         [val1, val2]
1  b  [val33, val9, val6]
2  a   [val2, val6, val7]
```

How do I get the lists into Dict:

```
pd.Series([a for b in df.val.tolist() for a in b]).value_counts().to_dict()
{'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val33': 1, 'val6': 2, 'val7': 1, 'val9': 1}
```

How do I get the lists by groups:

`df.groupby('id')["val"].apply(lambda x:  (list([a for b in x.tolist() for a in b]))`                )

```
id
a    [val1, val2, val2, val6, val7]
b               [val33, val9, val6]
Name: val, dtype: object
```

How do I get the lists by groups **as dicts**:

```
df.groupby('id')["val"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([a for b in x.tolist() for a in b]).value_counts().to_dict() )
```

Returns:

```
id       
a   val1     1.0
    val2     2.0
    val6     1.0
    val7     1.0
b   val33    1.0
    val6     1.0
    val9     1.0
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Desired output What am I overlooking? :

```
   id
   a     {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val6': 2, 'val7': 1}
   b     {'val33': 1, 'val6': 1,  'val9': 1}
   Name: val, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited using `agg` from @ayhan (much faster than apply).

```
from collections import Counter
df.groupby("id")["val"].agg(lambda x: Counter([a for b in x for a in b]))
```

Out:

```
id
a    {'val2': 2, 'val6': 1, 'val7': 1, 'val1': 1}
b              {'val9': 1, 'val33': 1, 'val6': 1}
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Time of this version:

```
%timeit df.groupby("id")["val"].agg(lambda x: Counter([a for b in x for a in b]))

1000 loops, best of 3: 820 µs per loop
```

Time of @ayhan version:

```
%timeit  df.groupby('id')["val"].agg(lambda x: pd.Series([a for b in x.tolist() for a in b]).value_counts().to_dict() )

100 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loo
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply is flexible. Whenever possible, it converts the returning object to something that is more usable. From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

> Some operations on the grouped data might not fit into either the
>   aggregate or transform categories. Or, you may simply want GroupBy to
>   infer how to combine the results. For these, use the apply function,
>   which can be substituted for both aggregate and transform in many
>   standard use cases.
>
> Note: apply can act as a reducer, transformer, or filter function,
>   depending on exactly what is passed to apply. So depending on the path
>   taken, and exactly what you are grouping. Thus the grouped columns(s)
>   may be included in the output as well as set the indices.

There can be cases, like this, that you want to avoid this behavior. If you are grouping, simply replace apply with agg:

```
df.groupby('id')["val"].agg(lambda x: pd.Series([a for b in x.tolist() for a in b]).value_counts().to_dict() )
Out: 
id
a    {'val1': 1, 'val7': 1, 'val6': 1, 'val2': 2}
b              {'val6': 1, 'val33': 1, 'val9': 1}
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Comment: Note that I am not going for speed here, I am just explaining why apply didn't behave the way you expected.

Comment: Not mean to bother,but why I get the result ` bulltin-methon-values of dict` ,how can i print the result like you?

Comment: @Tangfeifan It seems like a bug that has been fixed https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16741 I think version 0.21 hasn't been released yet though.