# Pandas difference between apply() and aggregate() functions

Tags: python, pandas

is there any difference in the (type) of the return value between the DataFrame.aggregate() and the DataFrame.apply() function if I just pass a function like

```
func=lambda x: x**2
```

because the return values seems to be pretty the same. And the documentation only tells:

> apply() --> applied : Series or DataFrame
>
> aggregate() --> aggregated : DataFrame

Comment: ... so, `apply` returns a `Series` or `DataFrame`, and `aggregate` returns a `DataFrame`. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two versions of agg (short for aggregate) and apply: The first is defined on groupby objects and the second one is defined on DataFrames.

If you consider `groupby.agg`  and `groupby.apply`, the main difference would be that the apply is flexible ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply)):

> Some operations on the grouped data might not fit into either the
>   aggregate or transform categories. Or, you may simply want GroupBy to
>   infer how to combine the results. For these, use the apply function,
>   which can be substituted for both aggregate and transform in many
>   standard use cases.
>
> Note: apply can act as a reducer, transformer, or filter function,
>   depending on exactly what is passed to apply. So depending on the path
>   taken, and exactly what you are grouping. Thus the grouped columns(s)
>   may be included in the output as well as set the indices.

See [Python Pandas : How to return grouped lists in a column as a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902042/python-pandas-how-to-return-grouped-lists-in-a-column-as-a-dict) for example for an illustration of how the returning type is automatically changed.

`groupby.agg`, on the other hand, is very good for applying cython optimized functions (i.e. being able to calculate `'sum'`, `'mean'`, `'std'` etc. very fast). It also allows calculating multiple (different) functions on different columns. For example,

```
df.groupby('some_column').agg({'first_column': ['mean', 'std'],
                               'second_column': ['sum', 'sem']}
```

calculates the mean and the standard deviation on the first column and sum and standard error of the mean on the second column. See [dplyr summarize equivalent in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935541/dplyr-summarize-equivalent-in-pandas/38935669) for more examples.

These differences are also summarized in [What is the difference between pandas agg and apply function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828398/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-agg-and-apply-function) But that one focuses on the differences between `groupby.agg` and `groupby.apply`.

`DataFrame.agg` is new in version 0.20. Earlier, we weren't able to apply multiple different functions to different columns because it was only possible with groupby objects. Now, you can summarize a DataFrame by calculating multiple different functions on its columns. Example from [Is there a pandas equivalent of dplyr::summarise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209908/is-there-a-pandas-equivalent-of-dplyrsummarise):

```
iris.agg({'sepal_width': 'min', 'petal_width': 'max'})

petal_width    2.5
sepal_width    2.0
dtype: float64

iris.agg({'sepal_width': ['min', 'median'], 'sepal_length': ['min', 'mean']})

        sepal_length  sepal_width
mean        5.843333          NaN
median           NaN          3.0
min         4.300000          2.0
```

This is not possible with `DataFrame.apply`. It either goes column by column or row by row and executes the same function on that column/row. For a single function like `lambda x: x**2` they produce the same results but their intended usage is very different.